# How to query on Category group to find all child or subcategories. ?

Tags: soql, sosl

I have an issue. In knowledge base  i have two Category groups, One is A and other is B. Now under A i have **ALL--->Subcategories**. Now i want to write a query which can get me all subcategories under A.
    Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you queried for the `dataCategory` you will have a recursive list of related subcategories

From there you can get the children `dataCategory` and stitch it all back together.